# How to handle custom token across pages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a custom log in that returns an encrypted Token, which indicates that a user is logged in. This Token is passed to another page(Dash.aspx) via QueryString.

Dash.aspx takes the token from the QueryString and posts it to a hidden field on the page.
Javascript reads that value and holds it in memory. That Token is then used to make web service calls. When these calls complete a new Token value is returned, and javascript stores that value (replacing the old one).

I want to add new pages for access after log in. These pages will need a valid Token passed to them. A user would move from Dash.aspx to one of these new pages and back (so just a few different links at the top of a Masterpage)

I don't like passing the Token via QueryString. And I am not sure how to keep the Token updated where accessible on page change.
I want to avoid using Session to store and pass the Token if possible

How can I pass my Token more discreetly and make sure it always passes the most up to date value?

I realize this is a fairly broad question, but im at a loss. I feel like there is probably some pre built idea that will handle this, i just dont know what or how to use it.

Thanks

**Update**

So an example was asked for:

Step 1: User logs in - > zholen/zholen123

- Service is called to validate username and password -> returns Token ('ABC')
- Redirect to Page Dash.aspx?token=ABC

Step 2: Dash.aspx grabs token from querystring and assigns to hidden field on page

- Javascript object grabs token from hidden field and stores internally
- JS Object makes several async calls to various services, each service returns 
  a new updated Token, internal token is updated with new value(**Tokens expire every 30 min**)

---

Desired new steps

Step 3: Move from Dash.aspx to Account.aspx

- Account.aspx requires valid Token to load
- Call more services and change Token

Step 4: Move from Account to Dash.aspx with up to date token

---

Service calls are made either via a Web Service(asmx) or through page methods depending whether the action desires a data return (asmx) or an html return(page method -> table prefilled with data) **or on page load**

Based on suggestion of Cookies, I think it would be possible to reset the cookie with the new token value during these calls on C# end, assuming that i could do that kind of thing from an ASMX and that the async of the whole thing wouldn't cause issues.

Also I can make the JS object which internally stores an up to date token place that value back into the hidden field if that would help make it accessible from the C# end.

Comment: I can't understand what you need. Can explain it with an example? Something like "The user logins, he is redirected to a new page with the token in the query string, then he click on ... and... javascript calls a web service and...)"

Comment: The cookies idea is good, but you cannot set them from an .asxm WS called from javascript. The hidden field value would be lost if the user changed from one page to other using a link or typing the URL, so you can discard this option. Are you using this token to keep session for 30 minutes? if so, why not use the regular session of ASP.NET? The answer solves the C# side of the problem, but not the javascript side. You have to set the cookie with javascript in a way compatible with all expected browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cookies... You may want to use your intermediate encryption as cookies can be read externally.

```
        //c#

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("myTokenCookie");
        cookie.Value = tokenString;
        Response.SetCookie(cookie);

        // then get it back later
        s = Request.Cookies["myTokenCookie"].Value;

        // then you could write it into a hidden input for retrieval in JS
```

Comment: although it's not so clear in the OP, it lloks like javascript calls a service and the cookie has to be changed at that moment. How would you handle the cookie change in the client side?

Comment: You can set cookies in javascript, too, though the code is a little more verbose.

Comment: To accomodate the javascript changing the cookie: since this is an ASP website it seems that if i place a hidden field on the page with a asp value (<% TOKEN %>) then if i update that value via javascript i can access the up to date token from the back.